# CakePHP response send is empty

Tags: cakephp, response

I am trying to create some generic return functions in CakePHP 2.5.3 to standardise the resposnes. I am using `Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml');`

```
protected function returnSuccess($data = null, $message = 'Success', $extraSerialize = array(), $statusCode = 200) {
    $this->set(array(
        'status' => true,
        'data' => $data,
        'message' => $message,
        '_serialize' => array_merge(array('status', 'data', 'message'), $extraSerialize)
    ));

    $this->response->statusCode($statusCode);
    $this->response->send();
    $this->_stop();
}


protected function returnError($data = null, $message = 'Error', $extraSerialize = array(), $statusCode = 400) {
    $this->set(array(
        'status' => false,
        'data' => $data,
        'message' => $message,
        '_serialize' => array_merge(array('status', 'data', 'message'), $extraSerialize)
    ));

    $this->response->statusCode($statusCode);
    $this->response->send();
    $this->_stop();
}
```

However the response is always empty. If I remove `$this->_stop();` than it works. However I would like the to stop the request then (especially on error).

Comment: Besides the problems with your code, why exactly would you want to exit the script at that point?

Comment: @ndm What is wrong with my code?  As for why I would want to exit here is an example. If I find the user doesn't have access to the item they are trying to get, I want it to return a 403 and stop executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aborting before the view is even being rendered, so that's the expected behavior.

Your `CakeResponse::send()` call actually has no effect (apart from possible headers being sent), and the only reason this is not causing an error is because the body that is being echoed is empty at that time, otherwise you'd receive a "*headers already sent*" error when Cake outputs the rendered data.

Personally I'd probably use exceptions instead of this manual sending/aborting stuff, something like

```
if(!$abc) {
    throw new ForbiddenException();
}

// ...
```

or a simple `return`

```
if(!$abc) {
    return $this->returnError();
}

// ...
```

where `returnError()` returns `$this->response`. Both would make invoking `send()` and `_stop()` unnecessary.

However, it's of course also possible to manually invoke view rendering

```
protected function returnError($data = null, $message = 'Error', $extraSerialize = array(), $statusCode = 400) {
    // ...

    $this->render();

    $this->response->statusCode($statusCode);
    $this->response->send();
    $this->_stop();
}
```

that way a proper body would be set for the response.

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html**

Comment: `$this->render();` works. Thank you very much. I have requirements to send the structured json with status, data and message every time, including errors. Otherwise I would have been happy to just throw and error.